# Displaying images and text from database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm attempting to retrieve images from my database and text to put it on the website. This is my code below:

```
<?php 
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("gamelogin");

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prezentacja ORDER BY id ASC");
    $img = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM img");

    $id = 'id';
    $text = 'text';
    $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
    $images = mysql_fetch_assoc($img);
?>

<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
      <title>Game Project</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/presentation.css">
      <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery.cslide.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
             $("#cslide-slides").cslide();
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="main">
         <div class="container">
            <section id="cslide-slides" class="cslide-slides-master clearfix">
               <div class="cslide-prev-next clearfix">
                  <span class="cslide-list"><a href="index_front.php">Lista gier</a></span>
                  <span class="cslide-prev">Poprzedni</span>
                  <span class="cslide-skip"><a href="main.html">Pomiń</a></span>
                  <span class="cslide-next">Następny</span>
               </div>
               <div class="cslide-slides-container clearfix">
                  <div class="cslide-slide">
                     <p>
                        <?php if($rows['id'] == 1) echo $rows['text']; ?>
                     </p>
                     <?php if($images['id'] == 1) echo "<div class=\"slajd_1\">"; ?> <img src="<?php echo $images["img"]; ?>"> <?php echo "</div>"; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="cslide-slide">
                     <p>
                        <?php if($rows['id'] == 1) echo $rows['text']; ?>
                     </p>
                     <?php if($images['id'] == 1) echo "<div class=\"slajd_2\">"; ?> <img src="<?php echo $images["img"]; ?>"> <?php echo "</div>"; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="cslide-slide">
                     <h2>This is slide 3</h2>
                     <p></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="cslide-slide">
                     <h2>This is slide 4</h2>
                     <p></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="cslide-slide">
                     <h2>This is slide 5</h2>
                     <p></p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </section>
            <!-- /sliding content section -->
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- #main -->
   </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to create some sort of presentation in html using PHP to retrieve text for each slide and images from MySql.

This part of code works perfect as I want it to work. I'm getting image and text if id = 1.

But when I'm trying to get image and text of id = 2 it breaks all the website and shows image and text that's id = 1.

```
<div class="cslide-slide">
   <p>
      <?php if($rows['id'] == 2) echo $rows['text']; ?>
   </p>
   <?php if($images['id'] == 2) echo "<div class=\"slajd_2\">"; ?>
   <img src="<?php echo $images["img"]; ?>"> <?php echo "</div>"; ?>          
</div>
```

Can you please take a look at this and help my to figure it out what it wrong ? Am I doing something wrong with id's ??

Comment: Is `id` primary key in your DB?

Comment: Does table `prezentacja` and `img` have same no. of rows?

Comment: Yes I have it set to PRIMARY KEY

Comment: You should pass `$rows` into a while loop, and loop through all your entires. On a side note, you should **really** stop using `mysql_` functions.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Umm No I don't think so. My img table have 2 columns: id and img. My prezentacja table have 3 columns: id, text, lang.

Comment: @Terry I tried to write while loop: 
<div class="cslide-slide">

                <?php 
                    while($photos=mysql_fetch_assoc($images)){
                
                        echo "<p>";
                            if($rows['id'] == 1) echo $rows['text'];
                        echo "</p>";
                            if($photos['id'] == 1) echo "<div class=\"slajd_1\">"; ?> <img src="<?php echo $images["img"]; ?>"> <?php echo "</div>";
                        }
                ?>
                </div>
But it don't really work there :/ am I passing wrong variables ?

Comment: If you're looping your the object returned as `$photos`, then you should refer to `$photos` in your loop, not `$rows`.

Comment: what is the relation between two tables  1:1, 1:m , m:m

Comment: @Terry but `$Photos` suppose to refer to images and get image from database, `$row` suppose to get text from database

Comment: Instead of running two concurrent queries, what about using a JOIN?

Comment: I'm not good with PHP, could you explain and show me an example of how to use it in this case ? And what is wrong with my `if` statement ? Why it doesn't get id value and pass it in the right palce ?

Comment: You have to write 2 while loops to match $img for each id.  It is much easier if you JOIN prezentacja and img tables.

Comment: @DanSin I tried a few more thing to figure this out but they didnt seem to work, I deleted another table for images and I added a column to 'prezentacja' table so I will add images only there where they should appear with both text and image. i tried to use `fetch-assoc` also but it didnt work :/

Comment: Are you using this cslide library? https://github.com/yvesh/cslide

Comment: @ChrisKucharzyk I wasn't talking about no. of columns, I was talking about no. of rows. Does table `prezentacja` and `img` have same no. of rows?

Comment: try `echo $rows;` and `echo mysql_num_rows($rows);` to check any records from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try my example if you would like to load more than one image:

```
<?php 
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("gamelogin");

    // add more field to store image paths
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM prezentacja ORDER BY id ASC"; // as mentioned, you put the img field into prezentacjatable
    $result = mysql_query($sql);  
?>

<html>
...
...
...
<div class="cslide-slides-container clearfix">
<?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<div class="cslide-slide">';
            echo '<p>'.$row["text"].'</p>';
            echo '<div class="slajd_'.$row["id"].'">';
                echo '<img src="'.$row["img1"].'" />';
                echo '<img src="'.$row["img2"].'" />';
                echo '<img src="'.$row["img3"].'" />';
            echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
?>
</div>
...
...
</html>
```

Comment: Ohh men this is really working as It should be, thank you very much. Can you please tell me one more thing. If I'd like to add 2 picuters on one slide, How should I do this ? Cause I can't add another path to img column in table cause it text so it will read everything there and it won't load any images. Should I create another table to separate images ? Or it is possible to do this in one table by adding another columns for more images ?

Comment: @ChrisKucharzyk If the numbers of images are known, i.e. 2 or 3 images, just add more columns is the easiest way to do so.  I wonder how cslide.js works.  Does it support multi-images or just like a slide show that you can put anything inside a <div> element?

Comment: It is really a hard job to combine PHP, HTML, CSS and Javascript together in one single page :p

Comment: it is working like a simple slide show that you can put anything on the slide.

Comment: Either you can add more fields to store image paths or save all image paths into one field seperated with commas.